# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, model, prediction

after i trained the keras model and saved now i want to test the model in different python file

my mode is machine translation in keras

```
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

print('1')
model = load_model('model.h5')
print('2')
model.summary()
print('3')
model.get_weights()
print('4')
model.optimizer
print('5')
# text = np.zeros("انت خوش لاعب")
text = np.array("انت خوش لاعب")
print('6')
print(model.predict(text))
print('7')
```

but when i run the above code i get an error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to
>   have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()